# How can I make only some files includable in c library using CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

If my library structure is

```
main.c
CMakeLists.txt
---- lib
---- CMakeLists.txt
-------- include
------------ Node.h
------------ LinkedList.h
------------ Queue.h
-------- src
------------ Node.c
------------ LinkedList.c
------------ Queue.c
```

My `add_library` code in `CMakeLists.txt` in `lib` folder is

```
add_library(
    lists
    lists/src/Node.c
    lists/src/LinkedList.c
    lists/src/Queue.c
)
target_include_directories(lists PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include}")
```

I want to be able to include only `Queue.h` outside library but `Node.h` & `LinkedList.h` only inside the library. How do I archive that? One way I tried was putting `Node.h` and `LinkedList.h` in src folder and adding these two in `add_library` as follows

```
add_library(
    lists
    lists/src/Node.h
    lists/src/Node.c
    lists/src/LinkedList.h
    lists/src/LinkedList.c
    lists/src/Queue.c
)
target_include_directories(lists PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include}")
```

But then I am not able to import `LinkedList.h` in `Queue.h`. What is the ideal way to achieve this access level?

Comment: One way is to have `target_include_directories(lists PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)`

Comment: But in that case I am not able to include LinkedList.h in Queue.h which is in include folder. @kaylum

Comment: What I mean is you can have both `target_include_directories`. One `PUBLIC` and one `PRIVATE`.

Comment: Nothing in cmake can prevent some header from being included anywhere using absolute or relative path. If you want to allow user to include only some "public interface" headers located in include folder then you'll need to implement some direction inclusion guards in other headers. *"But then I am not able to import LinkedList.h in Queue.h. "* - even if `LinkedList.h` is located in `src` folder, it can still be included into `Queue.h` using relative path `../../src/LinkedList.h`

Comment: @user7860670 thanks. Using relative path within library helps my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Queue.h` includes `LinkedList.h`, all tanslation units including `Queue.h` need access to `LinkedList.h` or they won't compile. (Ignoring preprocessor shenanigans here.) If you cannot get rid of the include you cannot accomplish your goal.

Depending on the uses of the contents of `LinkedList.h`, you may be able to remove the include:

- If you're using only references or pointers to types defined in `LinkedList.h`, you could get away with adding forward declarations to those types to `LinkedList.h`
- If you're currently using types from `LinkedList.h` in ways other than reference or pointer, the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) may allow you to get rid of this kind of usage.

---

If this is not an option, you may "hide away" those headers in a subdirectory with a name that indicated the headers are not meant to be included directly. I've seen `private` and `impl` being used.

Example:

```
include
--- lists
------ Queue.h
------ private
---------- LinkedList.h
---------- Node.h
```

Queue.h

```
...
#include "private/LinkedList.h"
...
```

When using your lib it should be easy to determine, if a header is supposed to be included or not:

```
#include <lists/Queue.h> // inclusion probably expected
#include <lists/private/Node.h> // probably you're not supposed to include this directly
```

If you want to be able to refer to the headers in the implementation of the library by a shorter path (`#include <LinkedList.h>`), you could add `include/lists/private` as private include directory making the shortened include path only available for the translation units of the library implementation:

```
target_include_directories(lists
    PUBLIC
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    PRIVATE
        include/lists/private
)
```